# How to save an XML file in Internal Storage Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity

I have posted a question with similar name. I tried to delete it, but since it has answer, I am not able to. However, question I have now is different, as I got stucked with the entire method. I apologise for possible inconveince and hope you'll still help me out.

**THIS IS MY CODE:**

```
public void fetchXML(){
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                URL url = new URL(urlString);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)
                url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.connect();
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

                xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                XmlPullParser myparser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();

                myparser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES
                        , false);
                myparser.setInput(is, null);
                parseXMLAndStoreIt(myparser);
                is.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    });

    thread.start();
}
```

**EXPLANATION:** `fetchXML()` is inside `HandleXML class` (HandleXML.java), so it is not in `MainActivity`, which I figured could be important, while copy / paste codes on how to Save Files from Web ( watched tutorials).  When I seem to implement codes like:

*COPIED FROM ANDROID TUTORIAL PAGE:*

```
String filename = "myfile";
String string = "Hello world!";
FileOutputStream outputStream;

try {
  outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
  outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I receive errors with `openFileOutput`.

**QUESTION:** How can I save the `InputStream` I get from `fetchXML()` the easiest way ? Code snippet would really be a savour.

Hope someone can help. Thanks.

Comment: Where did you put this 'save file' code? In your Handle XML class? Also post your logcat always.

Answer (score 1):

Exmaple for creating DOM xml file in internal storage:

```
public void CreateXmlFile(){
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = null;
        builder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.newDocument();

        // root element
        org.w3c.dom.Element root = doc.createElement("mobile-app");
        doc.appendChild(root);
        //create a comment
        Comment comment=doc.createComment("This is comment");
        //add in the root element
        root.appendChild(comment);

        prettyPrint(doc);
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public final void prettyPrint(Document xml) throws Exception {
    Transformer tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    Writer out = new StringWriter();
    tf.transform(new DOMSource(xml), new StreamResult(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/newXmlFile.xml"));
    System.out.println(out.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this method:

```
public void ConvertingAnInputStreamToAFile(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[inputStream.available()];
    inputStream.read(buffer);

    File targetFile = new File("targetFile.xml"); //<-- Your File Location here
    OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
    outStream.write(buffer);
}
```

Comment: hey did you try my answer ?